# programatically add google account to android

Tags: android, testing, account

I need to be able to programatically add a google account in android for testing purposes. The reason for this is because the data in the device can get wiped and I would like a way of easily adding the test users again with a function rather than doing it again manually.

any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

I dont have any experience in doing what you want. :)